# density of a set of discrete measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $F$ be the set of probability measures $\mu$ on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ such that its second order moment matrix is $M_\mu^2=\frac{1}{n}I_n$
$$F=\{\mu\in \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}), \ \ \ M_\mu^2=\frac{1}{n}I_n\}$$
where $I_n$ is the identity matrix and $M_\mu^2=\int xx^Td\mu(x)$

we note $F_d$ the discrete measures in $F$, I need to prove that $F_d$ is a dense set on $F$

help plz thanks in advance

Comment: A very long shot - this may help: my paper “A class of convex bodies”, Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, 145, 1969, 323-345.

Comment: yeah i knew it thanks so much